# SOX Recording on OSX not Working?

Tags: macos, audio, recording, sox

I'm running into issues with sox (http://sox.sourceforge.net/) failing to record on OSX.

I've tried hand compiling as well as installed via homebrew and get the same results.

```
    root# sudo ./sox -V6 -d test.wav
    ./sox: SoX v14.3.1
    time:  Apr 30 2011 10:35:05
    uname: Darwin IT.local 10.7.0 Darwin Kernel Version 10.7.0: Sat Jan 29 15:17:16 PST 2011; root:xnu-1504.9.37~1/RELEASE_I386 i386
    gcc:   4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)
    arch:  1288 48 88 L 

    Input File     : 'default' (coreaudio)
    Channels       : 2
    Sample Rate    : 48000
    Precision      : 16-bit
    Sample Encoding: 16-bit Signed Integer PCM
    Endian Type    : little
    Reverse Nibbles: no
    Reverse Bits   : no

    ./sox INFO sox: Overwriting `test.wav'
    ./sox DBUG wav: Writing Wave file: Microsoft PCM format, 2 channels, 48000 samp/sec
    ./sox DBUG wav:         192000 byte/sec, 4 block align, 16 bits/samp

    Output File    : 'test.wav'
    Channels       : 2
    Sample Rate    : 48000
    Precision      : 16-bit
    Sample Encoding: 16-bit Signed Integer PCM
    Endian Type    : little
    Reverse Nibbles: no
    Reverse Bits   : no
    Comment        : 'Processed by SoX'

    ./sox INFO sox: effects chain: input      48000Hz 2 channels 16 bits (multi)
    ./sox INFO sox: effects chain: output     48000Hz 2 channels 16 bits (multi)
    In:0.00% 00:00:00.00 [00:00:00.00] Out:0     [      |      ]        Clip:0    
    Done.
    ./sox DBUG wav: Finished writing Wave file, 0 data bytes 0 samples
```

As compared to running on Ubuntu:

```
    root# sox -V6 -d /tmp/test.wav
    /usr/local/bin/.libs/lt-sox: SoX v14.3.1
    time:  Jan 23 2011 06:26:14
    uname: Linux server 2.6.38-8-server #42-Ubuntu SMP Mon Apr 11 03:49:04 UTC 2011 x86_64
    gcc:   4.4.5
    arch:  1288 48 88 L OMP

    Input File     : 'default' (alsa)
    Channels       : 2
    Sample Rate    : 48000
    Precision      : 16-bit
    Sample Encoding: 16-bit Signed Integer PCM
    Endian Type    : little
    Reverse Nibbles: no
    Reverse Bits   : no

    /usr/local/bin/.libs/lt-sox INFO sox: Overwriting `/tmp/test.wav'
    /usr/local/bin/.libs/lt-sox DBUG wav: Writing Wave file: Microsoft PCM format, 2 channels, 48000 samp/sec
    /usr/local/bin/.libs/lt-sox DBUG wav:         192000 byte/sec, 4 block align, 16 bits/samp

    Output File    : '/tmp/test.wav'
    Channels       : 2
    Sample Rate    : 48000
    Precision      : 16-bit
    Sample Encoding: 16-bit Signed Integer PCM
    Endian Type    : little
    Reverse Nibbles: no
    Reverse Bits   : no
    Comment        : 'Processed by SoX'

    /usr/local/bin/.libs/lt-sox INFO sox: effects chain: input      48000Hz 2 channels 16 bits (multi)
    /usr/local/bin/.libs/lt-sox INFO sox: effects chain: output     48000Hz 2 channels 16 bits (multi)
    In:0.00% 00:00:07.94 [00:00:00.00] Out:377k  [      |      ]        Clip:0    ^C
    Aborted.
    /usr/local/bin/.libs/lt-sox DBUG wav: Finished writing Wave file, 1507328 data bytes 376832 samples
```

Can anyone else confirm this issue? Any ideas why?

Darwin unknown.local 10.7.0 Darwin Kernel Version 10.7.0: Sat Jan 29 15:17:16 PST 2011; root:xnu-1504.9.37~1/RELEASE_I386 i386

Answer (score 0):

Short story: SoX Bug on OSX, Fix is not yet in released versions.

Compile from source: http://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/forum.php?thread_name=D41696C9-E028-4111-AEC9-DE5C7D4C2C80%40qwest.net&forum_name=sox-users

```
git clone git://sox.git.sourceforge.net/gitroot/sox/sox
cd sox
osxbuild
```

(Doesn't address dependency issues, just the main issue reported above)